# Beautiful Soup - hyphenated keyword, Error :: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, keyword

I'm using Selenium and then Beautiful Soup to try an scrape a webpage, the page uses JavaScript to load certain content. Selenium has given me the plain html, I have checked this, using print and found that it does contain the part that im trying to scrape. But my problem is with Beautiful Soup.

I want to find the div tags with

```
class="comment-detail"
```

I've tried using

```
comments = soup.find_all("div", class_="comment-detail")
```

but this returns empty, maybe because the actual div tags also have in them

```
data-selenium="reviews-comments"
```

The exact tag in the html is

```
<div data-selenium="reviews-comments" class="comment-detail">
```

so I tried the following,

```
comments = soup.find_all("div", data-selenium="reviews-comments", class_="comment-detail")
```

but this gives the error

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

since

```
data-selenium
```

is like a subtraction operation when it is really just a hyphenated word. Ive tried enclosing it in quotation marks but that does not help.

Ive also tried

```
dct = {
    'div': '',
    'data-selenium': 'reviews-comments',
    'class': 'comment-detail'

}
comments = soup.find_all(**dct)
```

but

```
len(comments)
```

returns zero, i.e. comments is empty.

for the sake of clarity to get my soup i have the code

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get('http://www.agoda.com/the-coast-resort-koh-phangan/hotel/koh-phangan-th.html/')  
html_source = browser.page_source  
browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source,'html.parser')
```

Any ideas how to proceed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the URL, you have an extra forward slash at the end which returns a 404 page rather than the page you actually want. Just remove that and your code works fine.

Here's the code I used just in case:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
browser.get('http://www.agoda.com/the-coast-resort-koh-phangan/hotel/koh-phangan-th.html')  
html_source = browser.page_source  
browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')

comments = soup.find_all("div", class_="comment-detail")

print(comments)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!